# Is there a way to open in a new tab highlighted URL in the address bar?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox

Once you highlight the URL in the address bar without copy and paste in a new tab is it actually possible to open highlighted URL address in a new tab? Do Chrome or Firefox have these feature with any extensions ?

Comment: Questions about **general computing hardware and software are off-topic** for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [Super User](http://superuser.com/about).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you highlight the URL, use Alt + Enter on either browser.